# New job - no work for three months

Tags: work-environment, work-experience

I joined a job 3 months back as web developer. The company hired me for a big project and I have been sitting free for three months. There are other people in the project who have tasks. I am not being assigned any task. The project covers some 10 websites.

I feel like I have made a mistake joining here as I do not get any work.  I was thinking of getting shifted to some other project. My manager called me last week and asked me if there is a problem at official level and asked me if I want he can change me to another site under same project. I was very sick that day and told him so.

Now the thing is I do not want to work in this project even on another site as there is nothing to learn. I do not like the team. The manager laughs without reason when I interact with him and also when I take some time doing some thing. So it is clear he does not think I am capable and his behaviour makes me feel demoralized and depressed. I have lost all confidence in myself. That is why I  do not want to work under him.

The problem is if I resign, I look like a job hopper. If I ask for change, then I will be under him only. Please suggest me what to do.

Comment: If someone else will hire you after working at this job for 3 months, then they don't really think of you as a job hopper. Then you're under even more pressure to stay longer at the next job and I feel you're not easily satisfied. You could be coding and learning new things right now since you have so much time, but instead you're sulking.

Comment: Does the job have any sort of 'trial' or 'probation' period? If so, remember that such a period is **not only for them to decide if they like you but also for you to decide if you like them**.

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: If there is nothing to learn and the manager feels it is taking you too long then that is a problem.  When he laughs asks him straight out "Why do you you laugh?  Is there is a problem?".  M

Comment: I don't understand. What do you do during work hours if you are not given any work for months? What do you mean with "I was sick that day and told him so"?

Answer (score 14):

I am working in the same field since 12 years (Web development), and usually we don't assign the new developers big tasks from the beginning. New developer is supposed to practice the infrastructure and understand the business requirements before getting involved deeply.
3 months are fair enough to get started and be productive, **but they are not enough to like your team and be familiar with them**. so, in my opinion:

- Leaving your job fast is not a good idea, and bad indicator in your CV.
- I think your manager is smiling not laughing (which could be considered as fawning and friendly), but because you don't like him, you take his smile in ironical way :)
- As Abraham Lincoln said: "I don't like that man, I must get to know him better.", Try to understand your team more and to be involved more in their technical concerns. if you like your colleagues, manager, and working environment, this will definitely  be reflected on your productivity (like what you do to do what you like)
- Your manager might be under impression that you are not ready yet. ask him for tasks.

Answer (score 10):

You don't have to like your coworkers or boss, you have to learn to work with people you dislike as there will be someone like that in every job.

You need to focus on your own performance if you feel he doesn't trust you enough to assign you to anything. Talk to your boss privately about not being assigned anything and ask what you need to do. Find out why you are not getting the work you want and then fix that if possible. If they offer you another project, take it whether you want to work for the person or not. You have no leverage in an organization until you have shown that you are valuable.

Be proactive, don't wait to be assigned taks, ask for work every day until you get it. Look for things that aren't getting done and do them. Remeber no task is too small and no one will give you better assignments until you prove yourself.

Attitude is critical, too. If you are passive and unhappy at tasks you think are beneath you, then no one is going to give you better assignmetns.

Comment: if you dont like your coworkers and manager, then you are working in unhealthy working environment. Usually we spend time in work and act with coworkers more than our own family. so i think it is a key point in your success in work

Answer (score 2):

**Don't wait for work, find it**

First, okay so you're not getting assigned tasks. This happens new devs are usually put on really easy stuff or expected to shadow other devs to learn the system before they start getting real work to do. Three months is edging on the "too long" range, but not unheard of.

Still, with that if you're feeling under utilized go find work. Ask for tasks to do, if the won't assign anything to you, ask others in your team if there is something you can do to assist them, or if they still don't give you work ask informally what they'd work on if they had the time and go from there.

If you STILL can't get cooperation just do the work most devs are terrible at. Document stuff, write unit and integration tests, start reviewing code for "smelly code" or places that could perhaps be done better. Make whatever changes make sense then bring whomever is appropriate over and say "hey I saw an issue where this spot of code might *Whatever wasn't good about that code* so updated it to fix that, does this change make sense to you?" if they agree you can get it checked in, if not have them explain why and proceed accordingly.

**Career Missteps**

Lets say you look around and you see this simply is not someone you want to work for. For whatever reason it's just not a good fit and aside of sweeping culture changes you won't be happy here. (I don't think we're there, but I'm also on the outside of the issue)

Career missteps happen, they suck, but they're nothing new. Sometimes critical details are either not covered, or misrepresented during the interview and what sounds like an excellent job winds up being a nightmare.

As far as the CV goes I'd personally omit the job in question, when asked about the gap I'd explain I worked briefly for company X but it was clear right away the role wasn't a good fit. The interviewer will likely ask you to explain why it wasn't a good fit. When you explain why as well as what measures you're taking to prevent it happening again.

Most interviewers will have no problem disregarding a single misstep it happens to the best of us. If you have more than one then it's a bit less forgiving especially if we're talking a short time span. If you have three or more missteps you need to stop and change tactics in how you find work, because whatever you're doing it's not working.

**Job flipper**

Flipping a job isn't an exact science, but generally speaking if you don't put in at least two years at a job a fair number of people will see that is a flipped job. (Culture and field play heavily on what's considered a reasonable rate of changing jobs, the provided time is for Software developers in the US)

Flipping one job in a short window isn't that big a deal. Like I mentioned above you can explain it was a poor fit, and a one time offense is no problem so long as you've given me reasonably assurance you won't cut and run on me.

Now when you flip more than one job is where things start to get dicy. If you have really good reasons Job A folded, Job B the office relocated out of my commute range, Job C was a temporary role, etc. Job flipping can be overlooked so long as you can assure me I can count on you. This can happen just by circumstance, however; if your reasons aren't good it'll cost you getting the job. In addition as the number of jobs in a short time frame increase the odds I'm going to believe you decrease.

That said when you hit three flips without a good long job between them you're in a pretty bad place where your resume is going to struggle to survive the initial cut. This often leads to taking a less desirable role for a long time to do damage control before pursuing a better position.